# How to distinct "long", "double" and "const char *"

Tags: c

In 64bit linux, `sizeof(long)`, and `sizeof(const char*)` are same, I hope implement following code **without specific additional argument(I mean don't specific type argument)**

```
#define squeeze(smth) ({\
if (sizeof(smth) == sizeof(long)) {\
// do smth\
} else if (sizeof(smth) == sizeof(const char *)) {\
// do other\
}\
})
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is. The standard specifies some rather loose requirements, but it definitely doesn't guarantee that the sizes of those two types will be equal.

Comment: Why are you basing decisions on something like `sizeof(long)` vs `sizeof(const char *)`?  Use the [predefined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) for the memory model you're compiling for, which would normally be  `LP64` or `ILP32` for GCC, assuming Linux.  This situation is exactly what macros like that are predefined for.

Answer (score 5):

C11 introduces the `_Generic` keyword to do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, is C11 not C for some reason?

Comment: Sorry, I've been misreading. You are absolutely right, my comment is nonsensical. Gotta stop the all-night work... I reversed my vote.